# How to refer to a variable by its name

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

```
names(df.tot)
```

[1] "topic" "year"  "1"     "2"     "other" "tot"

```
df.tot$1
```

I have a data frame called df.tot; the variable name is a number, how may I refer to a variable by its name? the "df.tot$1" doesn't work!

Comment: Try using `` like `df.tot$\`1\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put "1" in quotes

```
df.tot$"1"
```